# Getting "Unsupported Media Type" error 415 (octet-stream)

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-headers

I developed a controller which generates an excel file with a chart, but when I change the attribute "produces" from the mapping, I always get the error as mentioned in the title.
This is the header from the postman
[image]

And, this is the controller code

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/exportfile/excel", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> exportExcel(@RequestBody ClientDataObjectRequest clientDataObjectRequest) {

        ByteArrayInputStream file = generateCSVExcelService.generateFileDetailsWithChart(clientDataObjectRequest);

        String dateFile = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(new java.util.Date());
        String timeFile = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm").format(new java.util.Date());
        String fileName = clientDataObjectRequest.getMetricName().replace(" ","_") + "_" + dateFile + "T" + timeFile;

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", fileName + ".xlsx");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        //headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".xlsx");
        //headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new InputStreamResource(file), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

As you can see, I'm using the "produces" as "APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE" as well as the headers request and response.
What am I missing here?

EDIT: I'm receiving a request body in a Json format

```
{
    "metricName":"Turnover Rate",
    "dataFormatCodeValue": "currency",
    "clientDataRequest":[
       {
          "clientName":"client 1",
          "value":"1"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 2",
          "value":"2"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 3",
          "value":"53.78"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 4",
          "value":"3"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 5555555",
          "value":"4"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 6",
          "value":"33"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 7",
          "value":"0"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 8",
          "value":"8.5"
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The [`Content-Type` HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) denotes the content type of the request. Are you actually sending an `octet-stream` as data? And what content-type have you configured for the endpoint to consume?

Comment: @Turing85 I'm not sure if I get your question. I have a request body in json format which I need to transform that in a downloadable excel file, and that is I'm trying to do with that code above.

Comment: If the request body is json, then you should send a `Content-Type` of `application/json`, not `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: What confuses me, though, is that postman normally sets the `Content-Type` header automatically to the content configured in the `Body` tab. Have you set the type in the `Body` tab to `json`?

Comment: So, I did both changes for content-type and still get the same error. Also, I set the type of body as a json. And you're right, the postman automatically sets the content type but I just want to make sure that is a octet-stream. Is the request and response header 'Accept' is needed to be changed or something?

Comment: Well, I changed the ```Content-Type``` to ```application/json``` and it worked. By the way, how can I assure that when the front-end calls the API and will get a downloadable file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. I had to put these both parameters inside the `@PostMapping`: `produces` and `consumes`

```
@PostMapping(value = "/exportfile/excel", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```